# Change Bar Colours in a Grouped Bar Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

My data consist of numerical values between 100 - 2000 grouped into 3 different drug treatment groups, which are then subdivided into 3 groups (based on their anatomical location in an organism, termed "Inner", "Middle", "Outer"). The final plot should be 3 groups of 3 bars (each representing the mean values of cell survival in each of the 3 locations). So far I have managed to make individual barplots, but I want to combine them. Here is some code that I have, and below that is a small excerpt from the data set.

```
Treatment   Inner   Middle  Outer
RAD          317    373      354
RAD          323    217      174
RAD          236    255      261
HUTS        1411    1844     1978
HUTS        1922    1756     1856
HUTS        1478    1711     1433
RGD         1433    1489     1633
RGD         1400    1500     1544
RGD         1222    1333     1444
```

With some help, I've been able to create a grouped bar plot using the code:

```
df %>%
  gather(key = group, value = value, -Treatment) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = value, fill = group)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "col", position = position_dodge())
```

Now, however, I want to be able to choose the colours of the bars.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: See `scale_fill_manual()` for controlling fill colors.  You may find [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/) on colors in ggplot2 useful, as well.

Comment: I'd consider a different visualisation to show the distribution of values, rather than masking them with the mean. For example, plot value versus group using `geom_jitter` or `geom_boxplot` and facet by treatment. Using your example data, this clearly shows that RAD has the largest effect on all groups, but that between-group effects are not large.

Comment: Thank you both for your great suggestions! I found scale_fill_manual() worked very well with my current code. Neilfws: how does geom_jitter work? I haven't come across that before.